# Support for https using QNetworkAccessManager. Hitting SslErrors at runtime

Tags: qt, https, network-programming, get, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am performing a https get operation with QNetworkAccessManager. I am hitting SSLErrors at runtime.
After researching for a while I was able to get my program running after installing OpenSSL. I required two dlls: libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll. Is it to say that I cannot perform https "get" operation using QNetworkAccessManager without OpenSSL ?? Doesn't Qt support native https support using QNetworkAccessManager.

Thanks,
De Costo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to install the following dll's found at the following website to my machine:
http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

The encryption is guarded closely by the nationality. So, More info at:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_can_i_add_ssl_support_to_my_qt_application